# Prevent any batch file from closing automatically

Tags: malware, windows, batch

I am worried my machine may be infected with malware. When I first log in there are batch scripts that open and close automatically very fast. Is there a way to see what program(s) executed a batch script or prevent any program that calls a batch script from closing? I would like to see the contents of the script when it is executed in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a program from Sysinternals Suite called [Autoruns](https://sysinternals-autoruns.en.lo4d.com/windows). It will list everything that is being started during logon so you can inspect the scripts and delete what you find malicious.

Trying to open Task Manager during logon will not be useful, as those scripts usually open and close too fast to be killed by Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that a malware program is using a batch script to run automatically when you log in.

To see what programs are executing batch scripts on your machine, you can use the Task Manager. To open the Task Manager, press Ctrl + Alt + Delete on your keyboard and then click on the "Task Manager" option. This will open a window that shows you all of the programs and processes that are currently running on your machine.

In the Task Manager window, click on the "Details" tab. This will show you a list of all of the processes that are currently running on your machine. Look for any processes that have "cmd.exe" or "command.com" in the "Image Name" column, as these are the programs that are used to run batch scripts.

If you see any suspicious programs or processes running on your machine, you can right-click on them and select "End Task" to stop them from running.

This will prevent the batch script from running automatically.
To see the contents of the batch script, you can try opening the script file in a text editor, such as Notepad. Batch script files typically have a .bat or .cmd file extension, so you can search for files with those extensions on your machine to try and find the script. Once you have found the script file, you can open it in a text editor to see its contents.

It's also a good idea to run a malware scan on your machine to make sure it is free from any infections. There are many antivirus programs available that can help you with this. It's important to keep your antivirus program up to date and run regular scans to help protect your machine from malware.

Comment: Usually scripts run fast enough that there's no time to open Task Manager and close them.